# Using HD 3000 with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I want to use a reasonably full version of OpenGL (with extensions, etc.) and use the HD 3000 integrated graphics on my i5 chip. How do I do this?

So far, I've managed to install a free version of OpenGL and glut... it works, but it's gimpy. And I feel pretty certain that it's running as software-only since it's pretty slow. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and programming in C.

Comment: "it works, but it's gimpy" - care to elaborate? Also, what is your operating system? On linux you need newest Mesa drivers, on windows there's an installer.

Comment: You might want to consider GLEW: http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel HD 3000 is not so bad!
It should support modern OpenGL (3.+)

install: http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/ and check version to be sure.

here is a link for HD 4000 on IvyBridge
http://www.geeks3d.com/20120506/intel-ivy-bridge-hd-graphics-4000-gpu-opengl-4-tessellation-tested/

Normally on Windows there is only OpenGL 1.1, but with usage os GLEW, GLEE libraries you can setup any version as you want (asumming that hardware supports that)

take a look at: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library

Comment: I picked up GPU Caps, which works... thanks... and I also got GLEW 1.9. But even though

Comment: I picked up GPU Caps, which works... thanks... and I also got GLEW 1.9. I copied glew.h files to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include, I copied the glew32.lib files to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib, and I copied glew32.dll to C:\Windows\system32 (I'm using Windows XP). Using Visual Studio Express 2010, I went to the project properties in linker->input and added glew32.lib, glu32.lib, and opengl32.lib to Additional Dependencies... and then it FINALLY worked. Anyway, thanks :)